# image_dataset_from_directory for multilabel classifcation

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm working on a multiclass multilabel classification problem, and I'm trying to approach the loading of images and dataset object creation from various angles.

Using a csv, xml, txt or decoding the labels from filenames is covered, but I tried to use tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory() to build the dataset, but it's not behaving as expected (or as I want). I haven't found any confirmation of whether it works or not like I intend it to.

My idea is to have the image repeated multiple times, in each directory of each class it belongs to.

Using 96 random pictures, I created a dataset like so:

```
main_directory/
...class_a/
......image_1.jpg
......image_2.jpg
        .
        .
        .
......image_96.jpg
...class_b/
......image_1.jpg
......image_2.jpg
        .
        .
        .
......image_96.jpg
...class_c/
......image_1.jpg
......image_2.jpg
        .
        .
        .
......image_96.jpg
```

The point is that all 96 images belong to all 3 classes, so every image tensor should have shape:

```
[[[image_1 pixels], [(1,1,1)]],
[[image_2 pixels], [(1,1,1)]],
              .
              .
              .
[[image_96 pixels], [(1,1,1)]]]
```

However, when I create the dataset object and print the batches to check if it's working correctly what I get is something like:

```
[[[image_1 pixels], [(1,0,0)]],
[[image_2 pixels], [(0,1,0)]],
              .
              .
              .
[[image_96 pixels], [(0,0,1)]]]
```

I'm confused by how it seems to assign classes. If assigns classes by either "first class assigned" or "last class assigned", given how it works in alphanumeric order, all images should belong to the same single class.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't managed to get `image_dataset_from_directory` to do multilabel out of the box. What I have ended up doing is creating a dataset with no labels e.g.:

```
ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
        image_dir,
        labels=None,
        ...
    )
```

Then I zip a manually created list of multilabels into this:

```
ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((ds, tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(labels_list)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing your approach. I abandoned this ppaorach and ended up diving palcing all images ina single dir and keep a csv file of filenames and their respective labels. Then I used the tf.data.Dataset API and created a full data pipeline. I ended up enjoying it better than using image_dataset_from_directory, but it did take some trial and error. If anybody reaches this from google, let me know if this approach works for you and I'll mark this answer as solution